# Pull value from hash reference

Tags: perl, soaplite

I am using Perl and [`SOAP::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP::Lite) to pull ticket information from a system called OTRS.

At the moment we have a web service set up on OTRS called GetTicket.

We've managed to get `SOAP:Lite` to connect to the web service and pull the ticket information. The ticket information comes back as hash reference.

I am not creating a hash reference inside of the code, that is just what is being returned. How do I pull apart that hash reference if I haven't created it?

At this point we are trying to loop through the hash reference using `foreach`. I will post my progress as I go through it, but as usual, any advice is appreciated.

**Perl Script**

```
#!perl -w

use SOAP::Lite;
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(SOAP::Lite
    -> proxy('https://ost-otrstest.ostusa.com/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/Test/GetTicket')
    -> GetTicket()
    -> result);
```

**Output**

```
$VAR1 = {
         'ErrorCode' => 'TicketGet.AuthFail'
         'ErrorMessage' => 'TicketGet: Authorization failing!'
        };
Press any key to continue...
```

EDIT: Added dumper and received an authorization error. We do have a user name and password, at this point I'm just not sure where to put that.

Comment: Check out the [Perl references manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: @daxim Do you have any idea on how to fix the AuthFail error that the OP is getting.  I can't think of anything I haven't used Perl in so long.

Comment: The code in your question is garbled.

Comment: @hobbs I just noticed I messed up a few lines, let me edit and fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SOAP::Lite` relies on `LWP::UserAgent` for a lot of its `http` functionality, including the behaviour when authorization is requested.

The documentation for `LWP::UserAgent` says this

> [get_basic_credentials] should return a username and password. It
>   should return an empty list to abort the authentication resolution
>   attempt. Subclasses can override this method to prompt the user for
>   the information.

So you need to overload `LWP::UserAgent::get_basic_credentials` by writing a new `SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials`.

Overloading this method is described in the [`SOAP::Transport`](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP%3a%3aTransport#HTTP-BASIC-AUTHENTICATION) documentation. You need to write this

```
BEGIN {
  sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
    return ('username', 'password');
  }
}
```

anywhere in your program. At the top is probably tidiest. (The `BEGIN` block forces the new method definition to be implemented before execution starts, regardless of its position in the program.)

I hope there is a better solution as I'm not very happy with this solution: it is an ugly piece of Perl programming. You may be better off subclassing `SOAP::Lite` altogether to make the interface a little tidier.

Comment: Ok, I'm experimenting with this now but still getting the authorization error. To me this looks like it is returning a username and password, is this true? If not, am I supposed to pass in the username and password I have?

Answer (score 1):

```
my $result = SOAP::Lite
    -> proxy('https://ost-otrstest.ostusa.com/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/Test/GetTicket')
    -> GetTicket()
    -> result;
```

To get one hash value:

```
my $errorcode = $result->{ErrorCode}; # TicketGet.AuthFail
```

To loop through them:

```
foreach my $key (keys %$result) {
     print "$key: " . $result->{$key};
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what we were doing with our code before but we are still getting that authorization error. As I said, I do have a username and password, I'm just not sure how to pass that information through SOAP::Lite. Do you have any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: You asked how to use the hash reference that was returned. I answered the question. Maybe you should edit your question.

Comment: Actually, it had been edited prior to you posting this answer. But thank you for your input.